# Create Event observer which fire when customer create while create order in magento admin

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, sales

I have create a SMS module which send sms to customer when a new customer create.
My config.xml is below :

```
...
<!-- Event for customer register success from frontend -->
<global>
    <events>
        <customer_register_success>
            <observers>
                <sms_customer_register_success>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>sms/observer</class>
                    <method>sendSmsOnCustomerCreate</method>
                </sms_customer_register_success>
            </observers>
        </customer_register_success>
    </events>
<global>
...
<!-- Event for customer register success from backend from manage customer -->
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <adminhtml_customer_save_after>
            <observers>
                <sms_customer_register_success>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>sms/observer</class>
                    <method>sendSmsOnCustomerCreate</method>
                </sms_customer_register_success>
            </observers>
        </adminhtml_customer_save_after>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
...
```

When I create customer while create order from magento admin as showing in below figure :

[image]

Then my observer is not working.

What event observer is fire when new customer create from sales_order_create?

Comment: Give this extension a try https://magecomp.com/magento-sms-notification.html